# Make a new Dataframe column based on key-value pair from a dictionary and an existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a dictionary:

```
acc_details = [{"account_number":100, "account_id":32}, {"account_number":32, "account_id":121},{"account_number":232, "account_id":12}, {"account_number":423, "account_id":56}]
```

and a Dataframe:

```
     transaction_value  account_number  ... fulfilment_date  tax_date
0                -2600            6827  ...             NaT       NaT
1               -21510            6830  ...             NaT       NaT
2               -83460            6825  ...             NaT       NaT
3                -2336            6650  ...             NaT       NaT
4               -65000            6303  ...             NaT       NaT
...                ...             ...  ...             ...       ...
```

I want to insert account_id which is in the dictionary in Dataframe as a new column based on the account_number which is already present in the Dataframe.
Account_number is already a column in Dataframe. But I want to put those account_ids which belong to specific account_numbers. Data of which is given in the dictionary. An appropriate account_id should be inserted based on the associated account number.

I have tried a lot of things but failed to make any difference. Also, I have no experience with Dataframe so any help would be great.

Comment: Do account numbers in the DataFrame suppose to intersect with account numbers in the dictionary? Now I don't see any association between them. Or is required just to substitute account numbers top to bottom and add associated IDs? Then there's insufficient number of them.

Comment: @n.shabankin Yes they are supposed to intersect and match and those which are not present or do not match can be NaN

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using pandas dataframe.
What you want to do is a dataframe merge, also called "left join" in the relational database world.

Suppose your original dataframe is called df

```
acc_details_df = pd.DataFrame(acc_details)

df_with_acc_id = df.merge(acc_details_df,on='account_number',how='left')
```

df_with_acc_id will carry the account_id column associated with account_number.